# how to make an onClick event run couple times in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a code which I pass it to the **onClick** event and I want it to be run 3 times:
(this code basically choose a random product from **products** and then by Hooks I update the state to show it in the shop cart and here actually instead of one I'm planing to show 3 random products. so I was thinking is there way to simply fire **onClick** 3 times with one click. )

```js
  const onRandom = () => {
        const randomItem = products[Math.floor(Math.random() * products.length)];
        const exist = cartItems.find((x) => x.id === randomItem.id);
        if (exist) {
          setCartItems(
            cartItems.map((x) =>
              x.id === randomItem.id ? { ...exist, qty: exist.qty + 1 } : x
            )
          );
        } else {
          setCartItems([...cartItems, { ...randomItem, qty: 1 }]);
        }
      };
```

I have used numourous ways but none of them seems working ...

```js
  const onRandom = () => {
            const randomItem = products[Math.floor(Math.random() * products.length)];
            const exist = cartItems.find((x) => x.id === randomItem.id);
            if (exist) {
              setCartItems(
                cartItems.map((x) =>
                  x.id === randomItem.id ? { ...exist, qty: exist.qty + 1 } : x
                )
              );
            } else {
              setCartItems([...cartItems, { ...randomItem, qty: 1 }]);
            }
           onRandom2();
          };   
      const onRandom2 = () => {
            const randomItem2 = products[Math.floor(Math.random() * products.length)];
            const exist2 = cartItems.find((x) => x.id === randomItem2.id);
            if (exist2) {
              setCartItems(
                cartItems.map((x) =>
                  x.id === randomItem2.id ? { ...exist2, qty: exist2.qty + 1 } : x
                )
              );
            } else {
              setCartItems([...cartItems, { ...randomItem2, qty: 1 }]);
            }
          };
```

I have also used **for** and **while** and changed the **const** to **var** and still I'm getting  one random product and there is even no error.
maybe I'm missing something about state implication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me demonstrate the issue using a simple example:

```js
function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);

  // Only adds 1 per click because counter stays the same (you
  // are working with an outdated counter). So you are simply
  // setting it 3 times to an increment of 1 using the same outdated
  // value for all 3 increments.
  function add3() {
    setCounter(counter + 1); // setCounter(0 + 1);
    setCounter(counter + 1); // setCounter(0 + 1);
    setCounter(counter + 1); // setCounter(0 + 1);
  }
  
  // Does add 3 per click because the counter passed to
  // the callback is the updated version.
  function add3Functional() {
    setCounter(counter => counter + 1); // setCounter(0 + 1);
    setCounter(counter => counter + 1); // setCounter(1 + 2);
    setCounter(counter => counter + 1); // setCounter(2 + 3);
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      {counter}
      <button onClick={add3}>add 3 (non-functional)</button>
      <button onClick={add3Functional}>add 3 (functional)</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Here is the relevant React documentation:

> ##### [Functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)
>
> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a
> function to `setState`. The function will receive the previous value,
> and return an updated value. Here’s an example of a counter component
> that uses both forms of `setState`:
>
> ```
> function Counter({initialCount}) {
>   const [count, setCount] = useState(initialCount);
>   return (
>     <>
>       Count: {count}
>       <button onClick={() => setCount(initialCount)}>Reset</button>
>       <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1)}>-</button>
>       <button onClick={() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)}>+</button>
>     </>
>   );
> }
> ```
>
> The ”+” and ”-” buttons use the functional form, because the updated
> value is based on the previous value. But the “Reset” button uses the
> normal form, because it always sets the count back to the initial
> value.

In short, if you want to update a state multiple times before a new render you should always use a functional update. In your scenario this means changing:

> ```
> setCartItems(
>   cartItems.map((x) =>
>     x.id === randomItem.id ? { ...exist, qty: exist.qty + 1 } : x
>   )
> );
> ```

Into

```
setCartItems((cartItems) => ( // <- uses the updated cartItems value 
  cartItems.map((x) => (
    x.id === randomItem.id ? { ...exist, qty: exist.qty + 1 } : x
  ))
));
```

**The same applies for your *else* scenario.**

---

After changing your `onRandom` function to use functional updates you can wrap the contents in a *for*-loop.

```
const onRandom = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    // add random item using functional update
  }
};
```

Or alternatively create a function that holds the logic and call it 3 times.

```
function onRandom() {
  addRandom();
  addRandom();
  addRandom();
}
```